# Why French word of url cannot be parsed by Node.js V6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, urlencode

I meet one issue, this url `'localhost:4020/share/Fr?chars=ECYCÉDN'` with French word can NOT be parsed in `Node V6.10.0`, however it could be parsed correctly under `Node V0.10.42`.

Here are more details for my codes

- The middleware for `Express`

  ```
  app.use bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })
  app.use bodyParser.json({ limit: '20mb' })
  app.use bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '20mb', extended: false })
  ```
- And output the `chars` in the above url router

  ```
  router = express.Router()
  router.get '/share/:lang', (req, res, next) ->
       console.log(req.query.chars)
  ```

I test this server with `curl 'localhost:4020/share/Fr?chars=ECYCÉDN'`, and the results are

- Node v0.10.42

  `{"chars":"ECYCÉDN"}`
- Node v6.10.0

  `{"chars":"ECYCÃ DN"}`

The express version is `4.15.2`

I want to know why this French word cannot be parsed correctly under Node V6.10.0?

I think it could be the character encode issue. However, I try to use `querystring.unescape` or `querystring.escape` of [`querystring`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/querystring.html), it does not work well.

---

**Update**

When I try to output `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.query))` in the router `'/share/:lang'`, the result is `{"chars":"ECYCÃ DN"}` and the length of `chars` is `8`.

Comment: This should not require more than about 10 lines of code to show as a [mcve]. Please update your question so that instead of just a few lines, it's just a runnable piece of code, with a short section that shows the dependencies - Node 0.10 is an obsolete version of Node, and whether code worked in it or not is essentially moot: you have a problem with Node 6 and Express. Presumably Express 4, but we won't know until you show the full code and list the used dependencies with their versions.

Comment: `require('querystring').parse('chars=ECYCÉDN')` works fine for me in node v7.7.1 and v6.10.3. I agree with @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, without a self-contained testcase this question is a little hard to answer.

Comment: I don't think the `bodyparser` has anything to do with parsing the `querystring`?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is within node and not, e.g. the shell you use for viewing the `console` output? Try logging `req.query.chars.length` as well.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I have updated my question, hope it could make it more clearly now..

Comment: @Bergi, Yes, I view it in the `console`, and the result of `console.log(req.query.chars.length)` is `8`.

Comment: @Blender, When I try to output `JSON.stringify(req.query))`, the result is `{"chars":"ECYCÃ DN"}`, it seems this French chars are parsed incorrectly .

Comment: @zangw: Can you test the code in my comment to figure out if the issue is with node or with express? Can you try using a web browser instead of curl to send the request? I don't think it's valid to have raw bytes in the query to begin with, since Chrome percent-encodes the UTF-8 encoding of your unicode string before sending it to the server.

Comment: possibly related: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8321, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111902/how-to-handle-get-parameters-containing-non-utf8-characters

Comment: @Blender, you are right, it works well when I try using web browser. It is related to url encode as Bergi mentioned.

Comment: @zangw again, please edit your post to show a [mcve] so people can see what you're really doing. You're still just showing a few unconnected lines of codes for something that should can be shown (with all the non-contributing code removed) in only a handful of lines.