# Handling UTF8 characters in express route parameters

Tags: node.js, express, utf-8, parameters

I'm having an issue with a NodeJS REST api created using express.
I have two calls, a get and a post set up like this:

```
router.get('/:id', (request, response) => {
    console.log(request.params.id);
});
router.post('/:id', (request, response) => {
    console.log(request.params.id);
});
```

now, I want the ID to be able to contain special characters (UTF8).
The problem is, when I use postman to test the requests, it looks like they are encoded very differently:

`GET http://localhost:3000/api/â` outputs `â`

`POST http://localhost:3000/api/â` outputs `Ã¢`

Does anyone have any idea what I am missing here?
I must mention that the post call also contains a file upload so the content type will be `multipart/form-data`

Answer (score 2):

You should encode your URL on the client and decode it on the server. See the following articles:

- [What is the proper way to URL encode Unicode characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912811/what-is-the-proper-way-to-url-encode-unicode-characters)
- [Can urls have UTF-8 characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22357509/can-urls-have-utf-8-characters)
- [Which characters make a URL invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid)

For JavaScript, [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) may come in handy.

Comment: actually, in this case I wanted the special characters to be in the url because there will be valid words in various languages. SO, I wanted them to be indexable and have the clear word in there

Comment: _NEVER_ use encodeURI, encodeURI guesses where your parameters starts and ends, it has no reliable way of knowing when you want to encode an actual `&`, and when you want to end a parameter and begin a new 1 (which is separated by `&`), never use it, always use encodeURIComponent instead, which is reliable and doesn't do any guessing.

Comment: I set up a quick node/express server on a macOS platform to test this and was able to successfully `console.log` the correct character for both GET and POST requests from a Postman client. I guess if UTF-8 character support for URL parameters is not part of the spec, then the results are going to be unpredictable. Maybe try re-encoding with `node-iconv`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14114534/305383

Answer (score 0):

It looks like postman does UTF-8 encoding but NOT proper url encoding.  Consequently, what you type in the request url box translates to something different than what would happen if you typed that url in a browser.

I'm requesting: GET `localhost/ä` but it encodes it on the wire as `localhost/Ã¤`
(This is now an invalid URL because it contains non ascii characters)

But when I type `localhost/ä` in to google chrome, it correctly encodes the request as `localhost/%C3%A4`

So you could try manually url encoding your request to `http://localhost:3000/api/%C3%A2`

In my opinion this is a bug (perhaps a regression).  I am using the latest version of PostMan v7.11.0 on MacOS.

Answer (score -1):

`Does anyone have any idea what I am missing here?`

yeah, it doesn't output `Ã¢`, it outputs `â`, but whatever you're checking the result with, think you're reading something else (`iso-8859-1` maybe?), not UTF-8, and renders it as `Ã¢`

Most likely, you're viewing the result in a web browser, and the web server is sending the wrong `Content-Type` header. try doing `header("Content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8");` or `header("Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8");` , then your browser should render your `â` correctly.

Comment: I am using Postman to make the two calls and the output I'm talking about is the `console.log(request.params.id)` from NodeJS. The get call has `Content-Type: application/json` in the header and the post call is `multipart/form-data` but none of them set an explicit charset in the request. The resulting difference in values in on the server side